# How to create layout that use header and footer partials

Tags: php, layout, view, yii2

I have red the guide about views and layouts, I have googled how to to this, but I still can not make it work. Here is the problem:

I want to have 2column.php and 3column.php layouts, where both are using _header.php and _footer.php partials.

2columns.php layout example:

```
render _header.php

$content and some other extra code

render _footer.php
```

Whatever I do I can not make it work. Can someone please post me real simple example of how to achieve this ? Thanks

Please note that answer:

use:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('@app/views/layouts/header.php'); ?>
    <!-- You may need to put some content here -->
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

does not help me... don't know what to do with it, I cant make it do what I need.

Comment: Have you tried using PHP `include 'file.php'` to include a header and footer file?

Comment: I was hoping for some Yii2 way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should simply try :

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<?= $this->render('@app/views/layouts/header', $_params_) ?>

<!-- main content -->

<?= $this->render('@app/views/layouts/footer', $_params_) ?>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

And don't forget to use the following in your header view :

```
<head>
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
    ...
</head>
```

Read more :

- About `render()` : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#render()-detail
- About layouts : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts

Comment: Finally... this works. I had `<?php $this->beginPage() ?>` in my header and `<?php $this->endPage() ?>` in my footer, so I had to remove them first and put them in main layout file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Normally you can also just specify the view as an absolute one: `//layouts/header`. That should also work.

Comment: @soju Hi! Why do not use `renderFile()` instead `render()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to render the header and footer:

```
echo \Yii::$app->view->renderFile('@app/views/layouts/footer.php');
```

Comment: I have tried that and I get messed up page, with no css applied to it. Css should be in the head section, but if I reader header like this I do not get it there.